# Show recursively data type

Tags: haskell

I have the following recursive data type :

```
data Person boss action = Person{
  salary  :: Float,
  subordinates :: [Person boss action],
  act :: action
  b :: boss
 }
```

and I need a function to print all the fields of the current Person and then call the function repeatedly. From what I can see show can only take one argument. I was trying something like:

```
instance (Show boss, Show action) => Show (Person boss action) where
    show  p =  (show (salary p) (act p) (b p)) map (\x -> show x) (subordinates p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `show` returns `String`, you can concatenate multiple invocations of `show` via `++:

```
instance (Show boss, Show action) => Show (Person boss action) where
    show  p =  "salary: " ++ show (salary p) ++ " act " ++ show (act p) ++ " b " ++ show (b p) ++ " subordinates " ++ intercalate "i " (map show (subordinates p))
```

For example, this code

```
import Data.List                                                                                                                                                                                        

data Person boss action = Person {
salary  :: Float,
subordinates :: [Person boss action],
act :: action,
b :: boss
}

instance (Show boss, Show action) => Show (Person boss action) where
    show  p =  "salary: " ++ show (salary p) ++ " act " ++ show (act p) ++ " b " ++ show (b p) ++ " subordinates " ++ intercalate "i " (map show (subordinates p))

main =
    let
        a = Person { salary=1, subordinates=[], act=1, b=1 }
        aa = Person { salary=2, subordinates=[a], act=2, b=2 }
    in
        do
            putStrLn $ show aa
```

outputs

```
salary: 2.0 act 2 b 2 subordinates salary: 1.0 act 1 b 1 subordinates
```

---

Incidentally, note that

```
map (\x -> show x) ...
```

can be written as

```
map show ...
```

Comment: you were right.. the lambda function was unnecessary.